# Using Drop-down with Check-boxes in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 2 drop-down boxes and i want the first drop-down to filter the 2nd one like cascading so the first one has check-boxes and i want to pass the selected items from the first one to the 2nd but getting a "syntax error". I run it into debug mode and the output result looks like this

```
CommandText "select  id, name FROM myTable where id in (''CKU019','CW5036'') "
```

and it seems there is extra apostrophe near CKU019.  Here is my code

```
protected void bindDDL()
    {
      string selectedValues = string.Empty;
      foreach (ListItem item in ddchkCountry.Items)
      {
        if (item.Selected)
          selectedValues += "'" + item.Value + "',";
      }
      if (selectedValues != string.Empty)
        selectedValues = selectedValues.Remove(selectedValues.Length - 1);
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select  id, name FROM myTable where id in ('" + selectedValues + "')", con);
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      da.Fill(ds);
      con.Close();
      facDDL.DataSource = ds;
      facDDL.DataTextField = "name";
      facDDL.DataValueField = "id";
      facDDL.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra ' wrapping your selected values...

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select  id, name FROM myTable where id in (" + selectedValues + ")", con);

Comment: No problem, please remember to mark this as the answer if it helped you.